# onSaveInstanceState and onPause change order?

Tags: android

Using Log.d() in these two methods, same code, on pause runs first on Android 2.2 but second on Android 4 after onSaveInstanceState.

Is that right?

Why the change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784610/onsaveinstancestate-and-onpause-call-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I used onPause to set variables which were read by onSaveInstanceState, which like I said never was a problem until Android 3 or 4.

The correct solution is to write your onSaveInstanceState so it is not dependent on onPause having run

Answer (score 0):

read out this-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29 this may helps